# Using fileuploader.js in codeigniter along with csrf in ajax

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, csrf, fine-uploader

How do I use fileuploader.js in Codeigniter with csrf, in ajax?

I am using the images_crud library http://www.web-and-development.com/image-crud-an-automatic-multiple-image-uploader-for-codeigniter/

I keep getting

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

**Added..**

I have added the `create` method in the controller :

```
/**
 * pages form
 */
public function create(){

    if(!isset($this->data['output'])){
        $this->data = array_merge($this->data, 
                        array(  'output'    => '' , 
                                'js_files'  => array() , 
                                'css_files' => array()
                            )
                        );
    }


    //-------------------------
    //for file uploading
    $image_crud = new image_CRUD();

    $image_crud->set_primary_key_field('id');
    $image_crud->set_url_field('filename');
    $image_crud->set_table('news')
        ->set_image_path('public/documents');

    $output = $image_crud->render();

    $this->data['output']=$output->output;
    $this->data['js_files']=$output->js_files;
    $this->data['css_files']=$output->css_files;
    //-------------------------


    //display
    $this->load->view('templates/admin_header');
    $this->load->view('admin/index.php');
    $this->load->view('admin/create_pages.php', $this->data);
    $this->load->view('templates/admin_footer');
}
```

And the `create_pages` in view :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<?php echo validation_errors()?>

<?php 
foreach($css_files as $file): ?>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $file; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php foreach($js_files as $file): ?>
<script src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></script>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php echo form_open(site_url('admin/pages/save'),array('style'=>'width:700px;'))?>

<label>
    Title
    <input type='text' name='title' value='<?php echo @$title?>' />
</label>
<br/>

content :
<textarea name="content" id="content" >
    <?php echo @$content?>
</textarea>
<br/>

<?php echo $output?>

<input type='submit' name='submit' value='save' />
</form>
```

I have added `image_crud.php` and `image_moo.php` in the library.

I am getting `500 Internal Server Error` with the url being 
    http://example.com/mole/pages/create/upload_file?qqfile=1355936206.9151.jpg

which I wanted to be
    http://example.com/mole/admin/pages/create/upload_file?qqfile=1355936206.9151.jpg

I am not sure why the `fileuploader.js` is taking a different url for uploading.

**Added**

Well, I have not made much changes to the codings avilaible from http://www.web-and-development.com/image-crud-an-automatic-multiple-image-uploader-for-codeigniter/

```
$(function(){
<?php if ( ! $unset_upload) {?>
    createUploader();
<?php }?>
    loadColorbox();
});
function loadColorbox()
{
$('.color-box').colorbox({
    rel: 'color-box'
});
}
function loadPhotoGallery(){
$.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo $ajax_list_url?>',
    dataType: 'text',
    data:$('input[type=hidden]').eq(1).prop('name')+':'+$('input[type=hidden]').eq(1).prop('value'),
    beforeSend: function()
    {
        $('.file-upload-messages-container:first').show();
        $('.file-upload-message').html("<?php echo $this->l('loading');?>");
    },
    complete: function()
    {
        $('.file-upload-messages-container').hide();
        $('.file-upload-message').html('');
    },
    success: function(data){
        $('#ajax-list').html(data);
        loadColorbox();
    }
});
}
function createUploader(){
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
            template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span><?php echo $this->l("upload-drop-area");?></span></div>' +
                '<div class="qq-upload-button"><?php echo $this->l("upload_button");?></div>' +
                '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
                '</div>',
            fileTemplate: '<li>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-file"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-spinner"></span>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-size"></span>' +
                '<a class="qq-upload-cancel" href="#"><?php echo $this->l("upload-cancel");?></a>' +
                '<span class="qq-upload-failed-text"><?php echo $this->l("upload-failed");?></span>' +
                '</li>',
            action: '<?php echo $upload_url?>',
            debug: true,
            onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){
                loadPhotoGallery();
            }
        });
}
function saveTitle(data_id, data_title)
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo $insert_title_url; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: {primary_key: data_id, value: data_title},
        beforeSend: function()
        {
            $('.file-upload-messages-container:first').show();
            $('.file-upload-message').html("<?php echo $this->l('saving_title');?>");
        },
        complete: function()
        {
            $('.file-upload-messages-container').hide();
            $('.file-upload-message').html('');
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: I have used it before. but you need to post your code so we can help :)

Comment: Yes, post your client-side code.  How can anyone possibly help otherwise?

Comment: Where exactly do you send the csrf token to the server ? Does this work without csrf enabled ?

Answer (score 1):

here you have two problems.

**First:** you need to set the **csrf token** with every ajax request. which is **simple**.

**Second:** you need to set the **csrf token** for when uploading. which is impossible.

But sure you have other alternatives here. **DON'T Worry!**.

each method like edit title or delete etc.. you can solve it like this:

in your `list.php` at the very first:

```
    $this->set_css('assets/image_crud/css/fileuploader.css');
    $this->set_css('assets/image_crud/css/photogallery.css');
    $this->set_css('assets/image_crud/css/colorbox.css');

    $this->set_js('assets/image_crud/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js');
    $this->set_js('assets/image_crud/js/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.js');
    $this->set_js('assets/image_crud/js/fileuploader.js');
    $this->set_js('assets/image_crud/js/jquery.colorbox-min.js');
    $CI =& get_instance(); // create codeigniter reference instance.
```

*Then:*

```
function saveTitle(data_id, data_title)
{
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $insert_title_url; ?>',
            type: 'post',
            data: {primary_key: data_id, value: data_title,
            '<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'},
            beforeSend: function()
            {
                $('.file-upload-messages-container:first').show();
                $('.file-upload-message').html("<?php echo $this->l('saving_title');?>");
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                $('.file-upload-messages-container').hide();
                $('.file-upload-message').html('');
            }
            });
}
```

simple solution. just adding the `csrf_token_name` and `csrf_hash_value`.

now for the **second problem** I said that it's impossible because the **qq.fileuploader**
uses `$_GET` and not `$_POST`, so the property `params` they offer just adds a get **argument for you** which will not be parsed by **csrf_verify()** method.
**how to solve it:** simply go to your `config/config.php` and add the following code to the end of it:

```
if(stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/upload_file') === FALSE)
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
}
```

which will disable the uploading csrf checking for you ( it will be disabled just when uploading ) and it will re-enable it with the next request.

I have tested this code and it's working 100%. :)

**Update:** the main problem consists of that the developer of image_crud has not considered **multipart encoded request** ( as I can see from the new results). and he is using an old version of **fineuploader**. the problem is solved by **fineuploader 3.0+** but not yet in **image_crud** which is making problems when using multipart encoded request.

*Hope that I helped.*

Comment: qq.fileuploader does not send GET requests.  Never has, never will.  The presence of parameters in the query string does not mean the request is a GET request.  qq.fileUploader sends POST requests.  The way to solve the 2nd problem is to upgrade to a newer version of the uploader code where users have the option to have all parameters sent exclusively in the request body.

Comment: I am sure that I read that in github discussion. and I checked it. and I can provide the params output for you. @RayNicholus

Comment: I maintain that project.  qq.fileUploader does not send GET requests.

Comment: @RayNicholus - one minute and I'll post a look like for you. just one minute :)

Comment: @RayNicholus - http://localhost/imgcrud/index.php/images_examples/example4/upload_file?csrf_test_name=b48081a04c854ce1936a9d50583ee79e&qqfile=08_10_12_023739_0-1197249.jpg

Comment: this is how it look like when you add params :)

Comment: @RayNicholus - one more thing. [here](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/issues/86) you can find a great discussion supports my answer :)

Comment: It sounds like you think the request method can be determined by simply looking at the URL.  That is not correct.  It also sounds like you think the $_GET global in PHP is used to parse parameters for GET requests.  This is also not true.  This is apparently a common misconception.  I explained how $_GET and $_POST in PHP work to another uploader user in [this post here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fineuploader/gm7Wk0yoyxM/Rq0OGJ_fo80J).  Have a read.

Comment: and the image_crud the OP using built over paramsInBody = false. if you turn it to true. you have to rewrite the image_crud all over to fit the multipart encoding issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22650/discussion-between-mamdouh-alramadan-and-ray-nicholus)

Answer (score 0):

The author of image_crud has just pushed out a new version that utilizes the latest version of Fine Uploader.  Problems with IE and other issues you may have run into should be fixed in the newest version.  You should be able to make use of csrf tokens now without minimal reconfiguration.