# fineuploader + codeigniter CSRF protection

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf, fine-uploader

I'm using fineuploader and codeigniter. To make the upload more secure, I would like to use the CSRF protection provided by codeigniter by enabling it in the config. Now, when using the form helper of codeigniter, it automatically adds a hidden field to the form.

However, I don't know how I can realize this with fineuploader, as I don't have a visible form here. 
Any tips?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#bootstrapped-fine-uploader').fineUploader({
              request: {
                    endpoint: "<?= site_url('upload/doUpload') ?>",
  params: {"generateError": true}
  },
  chunking: {
  enabled: true
  },
  debug: true,
  text: {
  uploadButton: '<div><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Datei auswählen</div>'
            },
              template: '<div class="qq-uploader span12">' +
                      '<pre class="qq-upload-drop-area span12"><span>{dragZoneText}</span></pre>' +
                      '<div class="qq-upload-button btn btn-success">{uploadButtonText}</div>' +
                      '<span class="qq-drop-processing"><span>{dropProcessingText}</span><span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span></span>' +
                      '<ul class="qq-upload-list" style="margin-top: 10px; text-align: center;"></ul>' +
                      '</div>',
  validation: {
  allowedExtensions: [],
  sizeLimit: 1000 * 1000 * 800
  },
  showMessage: function(message) {
  // Using Twitter Bootstrap's classes and jQuery selector and method
  $('.qq-upload-list').append('<li class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</li>');
        },
        failedUploadTextDisplay: {
            mode: 'custom',
            maxChars: 100,
            responseProperty: 'error',
            enableTooltip: true
        },
        classes: {
            success: 'alert alert-success',
            fail: 'alert alert-error'
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: false
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294672/using-fileuploader-js-in-codeigniter-along-with-csrf-in-ajax/14299951#14299951)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I added

data: {'<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>':'<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'}

to my code but it doesn't work anymore. The fineuploader isn't showing anymore after adding this.

Comment: Is your Javascript console reporting any import errors or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the CSRF token and hash in your parameters being sent along with the upload request, and then verify it server-side.

Fine Uploader, by default, sends data for POST requests in the body of the request. And this is the ideal cross-browser solution. You can modify the parameters being sent in the request by adding keys/values to the `params` option. Modify your client-side code like so:

```js
// snip ...
params: {
    "generateError": true,
    "<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>":"<?php echo $CI->security->get_csrf_hash()"
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works fine! I didn't put it under "params", that did the trick.

Comment: This does not work when using the Amazon S3 uploader.

Comment: See https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/996 for the specific issue related to the S3 uploader and CSRF tokens. Vote on it, or provide feedback if it's something you would like to see implemented. We are planning 4.2 right now, so it'd be a good time to chime in!